# Build error "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process" in WP7?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I guess we can add this question to the list. Basically It's been taking me twice the time to try something out because everytime I try to debug my app I have to wait about a minute to lauch the app. There are 3 files in order that it complains about.

1. Resources file (.g)
2. Program Debug Database
3. DLL (.dll)

I tried removing the first two, but then it complains about the DLL file. Strangely enough I have never encountered this and I've been using the the WP7 emulator in VS2010 for about a year. Any ideas? Is there possibly a setting or cache that can be deactivated?

Comment: What's your assembly version in `AssemblyInfo.cs`?

Comment: It was a random question, but I remember seeing a similar issue (not WP7) which was related to the assembly version.

Comment: Yeah like I said I'm not sure what the problem is. I never went into the AssemblyInfo file. What ended up being the solution?

Comment: I sometimes have the same issue when my application is already running and I want to build it again (F6).

Comment: The user was using `*` to fill up the rest of the assembly info. (S)he replaced it with `1.0.0.0` and it started working. You could try the workaround suggested here as it may be a VS bug. Essentially the pre-build command will delete the existing version if it's there and locked: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/571961/bug-on-build-solution-unable-to-copy-file-because-it-is-being-used-by-another-process

Comment: I found out what it was. I'm posting an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically when you add images to your project, by default they are added as a resource. By doing this everytime you try to build the project the images are saved in the dll file thus the long wait time. I set 95% of my images to content and have not had the issue since.